# JPA perform part of an query if a value is not null

Tags: jpa

in Java the following is a common idiom:

```
if( null != obj && obj.getSomeNumber() > 0 ) { ... }
```

This will perform the length check only, if *null != obj* is true.
However, in a JPA NamedQuery this does not work:

```
@NamedQuery(
name = "query"
query = "SELECT o FROM SomeObjectList o WHERE o.someObject is not null AND o.someObject.someNumber > 0")
```

(This is what I've expected, as this would also not work in SQL.)

o.someObject is either 'null' or an foreign key to a table where SomeObjects are stored. (Each column of the table corresponds to an attribute of SomeObject.)

```
-------------------------           ----------------------------
| Table: SomeObjectList |           |    Table: SomeObject     |
-------------------------           ----------------------------
|  id   |   someObject  |           |  id    |  number |  name |
-------------------------           ----------------------------
|   1   |        4      |           |   3    |    -4   | foo   |
-------------------------           ----------------------------
|   2   |       null    |           |   4    |     2   |  bar  |
-------------------------           ----------------------------
```

So I'd like to create a NamedQuery which will return all Objects from SomeObjectList which either have no object (someObject == null) or where SomeObject.number > 0. 
Currently, I obtain all objects and check myself if someObject is set.

But is there a way to get an similar behavior in JPA or does I have to perform the checks on the returned objects?

edit: Added graphics and clarified the problem. (Thanks to James.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use an outer join for this.

Note your query is wrong, you want seem to want an OR not an AND, otherwise just remove the null check.

```
SELECT o FROM SomeObjectList o left join o.someObject so WHERE o.someObject is null OR so.someNumber > 0
```

Comment: Thank you, seems to work. But shouldn't "is not null AND" be the same as "is null OR"?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand?

You don't even need the "not null", just the length > 0 will not return true for null?

Also your code is wrong, length is a function, not a navigation.

It should be,

```
SELECT o FROM SomeObject o WHERE LENGTH(o.arry) > 0
```

Or is arry a collection relationship?  In this case you would need to use SIZE, and the join will also filter absent relationships.

Comment: 'length' should be just a colum of the database. I choosed this, so it could be compared to my java comparison, but that seems to be not a good choice...edited it. Thanks!